# Who is this 'strong guy' in Misfits?

Tags: character-identification, misfits

When I noticed when seeing the Misfits intro which happens in every episode of Misfits, I saw this:

[image]

In the third series, first episode I also noticed the probation worker has some strength power, is this him surely, however, I don't see him being one of *them* due to his attitude.

Does anyone know anything further about the plot?

Comment: The probation worker has some strength power? I didn't notice this. I remember him slamming Rudy against a locker, but that didn't seem to involve any unusual levels of strength.

Comment: He broke a padlock with his foot in the first episode.

Comment: The padlock that Rudy put on the locker he explicitly *wanted* the probation worker to open (so he could find the dog that Rudy planted there)?

Comment: Nope, not that part. He broke a padlock that was locked on a toolbox, he just simply pushed it with his foot and took a sandwich or something (forgot what he took out).

Comment: Correction, he took out some money in the dog donation chestbox for the food/drink machine: http://www.channel4.com/programmes/misfits/4od#3251420 - skip to 6:01.

Comment: Ok, I remember that now. I can't watch that video (it is apparently region restricted), but the implication of the episode was pretty clear that the dog was a resource he regularly ransacked for change to purchase snacks with. I suspect the lock was simply broken, and he would put it back once he took what he wanted so that people would be inclined to donate more. This is why he was so upset when Rudy stole it. I'll have to re-watch that part later, but I'm still not convinced it was a demonstration of super-strength.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's the probation worker from the first episode, [Tony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Misfits_characters#Other_characters).  When the storm hit, he was given superstrength, but he was also out of his mind when his powers were active.  He's the fellow the group killed in the first episode, because he was attacking them.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Hardly ever thought about Tony! My mind doubted it was the rude probation worker since he died recently (like another says "Not another probation worker!"). Thanks! :P