# Why does a wolf appear alongside Nathan in the "Misfits" opening credits?

Tags: misfits

The opening credits for "Misfits" are quite clever (and can be viewed [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nu80V4XI52k)) and contain a few clues to mysteries that unravel over the course of the first series (for that reason I am using some *spoiler tags*). In the first group shot, some of the shadows display their powers:

[image]

- Simon can turn invisible
- Kelly can hear thoughts, or "see" into people's minds

> - Nathan is immortal and dies a lot

Then in the second half of the opening credits, all 5 cast members are spotlighted, with video footage of them alongside animation approximating their powers.

- Curtis' shadow lags behind him as if he's time traveling
- Simon's shadow disappears
- Kelly and Alisha have radar coming towards and away from them, which I can stretch to fit with their powers of telepathy and skin-contact-induced hypersexuality

But Nathan's is a wolf. A wolf appears behind him.

[image]

> Nathan's power is a mystery throughout the first season, and we're led to believe he does not have a power. The only clue to his power is this wolf thing in the opening credits, and I was surprised when his power was revealed in the first series finale and it had nothing to do with wolves.

Why is this? Does the wolf symbolize something?

Comment: Black jackal = egyptian god of dead!

Comment: He is clearly immortal and the way he just looks around casually here and turns away from the wolf right behind him, completely undisturbed by it illustrates how danger is not a threat to him due to his immortality power.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The black dog is a portent of death in many English folk tales. Nathan is being tracked by it, but as he can't die, is not caught, just followed. There are plenty of references on the net as many localities have their own versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a reference to Nathan's mother's boyfriend, [Jeremy](http://e4-misfits.wikia.com/wiki/Jeremy).  During S1E2, it's pretty heavily implied that Jeremy became a werewolf due to the storm, but this was later shown to be false.  His power (or mental illness), causes him to roam the city at night naked, believing himself to be his childhood dog.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too, but it's odd that they would reference his mom's boyfriend when everyone else's animation references their powers and not someone else's.

Comment: [Not all](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/who-is-this-strong-guy-in-misfits) of the silhouettes are our main characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is being looked into too deeply - I've always thought (obviously, since I found out about Nathan's ability. I didn't just guess) that the wolf in question has just killed Nathan (hence the drop of blood from its mouth), only for him to walk away after it.

Answer (score -1):

A lone wolf as Nathan is immortal he will roam around the world while every one dies a lone wolf  lives alone

Answer (score -2):

I think that the reason behind the wolf is that Nathan in fact is not immortal;

1. The animal symbols for 'immortality' are not wolves because wolves refers to land, the evil, devouring passion and fury.
2. How do we know that in fact Nathan isn't being reborn 'the phoenix' "from the fires to ashes to new life"?
3. Nathan could be using a healing factor (like Wolverine) and think he's immortal.